# Can WebAssembly get javascript callback?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, event-driven

Is it possible to pass javascript callback to WebAssembly?
Can we trigger an event from WebAssembly and listen to it in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@KevinHoffman/javascript-interop-with-webassembly-2c69a3db19e9) from Kevin Hoffman attempting this using rust.

It boils down to using `WebAssembly.instantiate(bufferSource, importObject)` optional `importObject`. You can read more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiate).

Here is the example for the article

### Web Client

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>

   function logit() {
     console.log('this was invoked by Rust, written in JS');
   }

   let imports = {logit};

   fetch('wasm_project.gc.wasm')
     .then(r => r.arrayBuffer() )
     .then(r => WebAssembly.instantiate(r, { env: imports }))
     .then(wasm_module => {
       alert(`2 + 1 = ${wasm_module.instance.exports.add_one(2)}`);
     });
   </script>

 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

### Rust prototype

```
extern "C" {
   fn logit();
}
```

### Rust

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add_one(a: u32) -> u32 {
    logit();
    a + 1
}
```

### Credit

All credit goes to Kevin Hoffman's [Article](https://medium.com/@KevinHoffman/javascript-interop-with-webassembly-2c69a3db19e9)

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you have to use a function table from the webassembly side. What it does its just referencing functions by index in a table and calling them with a dynamic index using `call_indirect`.
**Note:** The table is a core thing of webassembly but I don't know how it is implemented in other languages other than WebAssembly-Text (wat). The `call_indirect` is the binary instruction's name